# I cannot edit Excel documents in SharePoint and when I check out and edit the document, my changes are not saved

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have edit privileges for my clients SharePoint Library. I am not able to edit the excel doc while in the library and when I check it out and edit, the changes are not saved. They have doubled checked this on their end using my access info and have confirmed all is in order on their end.

Appreciate any help you can provide. I am working off a new computer with the latest IE version.

Comment: what error you are getting?